# How to create a simple article design with CSS and HTML5

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the following design:
[image]

This is my code so far.

```
<section class="frontpagearticle">
    <figure class="frontpagearticlefigure">
        <img class="frontpagearticleimg" />
    </figure>  
    <header>  
        <h2 class="frontpagearticleh2">MyHeader</h2><time class="frontpagearticletime">pubtime</time>  
    </header> 
    <p class="frontpagearticletext">Lorem....</p>
    <a href="">Read more...</a>
</section>
```

I'm having problems creating my css, so ex. pubtime would be align to the right, while MyHeader would be left align.

The image is always going to be the same size.

```
height: 140px;
width: 250px;
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E5LFc/ for people to play with :)

Comment: What have you tried? What, specifically, isn't working? You'll get far more quality answers if you provide more detail about what you did and ask a specific, pointed question rather than asking people to do your work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/E5LFc/1/) My attempt at making it, as simple as I could :)